# How to fix group by in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Customers = id, etc
Bikes = id, customer_id, etc
Services = id, bike_id etc
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
customer_name | customer_email | last_service | total_service
```

I've tried it on MySQL front and it works:

```
select c.name, c.email, max(s.created_at) as last_service, count(s.id) as total_service
from customers c
inner join bikes b
on b.id = c.id
inner join services s
on s.bike_id = b.id
group by c.id
```

But in Laravel it gives me an error:

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')
            ->join('bikes', 'customers.id', '=', 'bikes.customer_id')
            ->join('services', 'bikes.id', '=', 'services.bike_id')
            ->select('customers.*', DB::raw('max(service.created_at) as last_service'), DB::raw('count(service.id) as total_service'))
            ->orderBy('total_service', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('customers.id')
            ->get();
```

I got error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db_safahonda.customers.customer_name' isn't in GROUP BY
```

On the other same problem, some people answer to change `MySQL strict to false` on `config/database.php`.

It works on my view and dd, but all my `last_service` still show the same date.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Laravel allows some shorthand with the groupBy method, but MySQL and other DB's need to know how to handle the other fields. Since you are selecting * it's bringing in the whole lot.

Try adding `max(customer_name)` to to the select statement, you may need to repeat for additional fields, to give mysql a function to aggregate the fields (max of a string is silly but it solves the problem, since first and last don't exist here).

Answer (score 0):

Any value selected outside of an aggregate function (`max()`, `count()`, etc.) does need to be part of the `group by` clause.

Adding the other `customers` table columns to the `group by` clause will solve your issue following strict standards (it will be a list of strings, see Laravel documentation link below), as would selecting all the other columns from the `customers` table with aggregate functions (as mentioned in the other answer).

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset